# Select specific column based on data supplied using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that may have unknown headers, one of the columns will contain email addresses for example.

Is there a way to select only the column that contains the email addresses and save it as a list to a variable?

One csv could have the header say email, another could say emailaddresses, another could say email addresses another file might not even have the word email in the header. As you can see, the headers are different. So I want to be able to detect the correct column first and use that data further in the script. Once the column is identified based on the data it contains, select that column only.

I've tried the where-object and select-string cmdlets. With both, the output is the entire array and not just the data in the column I am wanting.

```
$CSV = import-csv file.csv
$CSV | Where {$_ -like "*@domain.com"}
```

This outputs the entire array as all rows will contain this data.

Comment: The answer is that this is probably possible, but you need to provide some sample CSV data and also your attempt to write the code to get the data you need.

Comment: I've provided an example of how the data might be presented. The headers in the csv are unknown as they will be user created. I want to select the specific column that contains the data I'm filtering against. Only this column. I don't care what that column name is. For example, email addresses always follow the format name@domain.com. So if the filter searches for the column following this format, I want to output it. Not the entire object and all it's properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sample Data for visualization

```
id,first_name,bagel,last_name
1,Base,bcruikshank0@homestead.com,Cruikshank
2,Regan,rbriamo1@ebay.co.uk,Briamo
3,Ryley,rsacase2@mysql.com,Sacase
4,Siobhan,sdonnett3@is.gd,Donnett
5,Patty,pesmonde4@diigo.com,Esmonde
```

Bagel is obviously what we are trying to find. And we will play pretend in that we have no knowledge of the columns name or position ahead of time.

### Find column dynamically

```
# Import the CSV
$data = Import-CSV $path

# Take the first row and get its columns
$columns = $data[0].psobject.properties.name

# Cycle the columns to find the one that has an email address for a row value
# Use a VERY crude regex to validate an email address.
$emailColumn = $columns | Where-Object{$data[0].$_ -match ".*@*.\..*"} 

# Example of using the found column(s) to display data.
$data | Select-Object $emailColumn
```

Basically read in the CSV like normal and use the first columns data to try and figure out where the email address column is. There is a caveat that if there is more than one column that matches it will get returned.

To enforce only 1 result a simple pipe to `Select-Object -First 1` will handle that. Then you just have to hope the first one is the "right" one.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. I wonder if there is a way to have it stop as soon as it finds the first result. I doubt I'll have more than one column with this information but couldn't hurt to try and figure that part out. Thank you very much.

Comment: `$emailColumn = $columns | Where-Object{$data[0].$_ -match ".*@*.\..*"} | Select -First 1`. If you have at least PS v3 that will actually stop processing more columns (PS <3 will still only return 1 result but process all columns). Not likely an issue since it should be able to work trough a large number of columns quickly

Comment: Yesn but if first line dont contain email?

Comment: The first match... not the first column

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Import-Csv`, the result is a `PSCustomObject`.

```
$CsvObject = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Example.csv'

$Header = ($CsvObject | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*email*' }).Name

$CsvObject.$Header
```

This filters for the header containing `email`, then selects that column from the object.

---

Edit for requirement:

```
$Str = @((Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Example.csv') -like '*@domain.com*')
$Headers = @((Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Example.csv' -TotalCount 1) -split ',')

$Str | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header $Headers
```

Comment: No way to base it on the data that column contains? For example if it contain @domain.com on column 1 select that column specifically.

Comment: @CrypticSage Sure, pipe the last line like: `| Where-Object { $_ -like '*@domain.com' }`

Comment: @CrypticSage If you want the whole row, you could do something like: `$CsvObject | Where-Object { $_.$Header -like '*@domain.com*' }`

Comment: That's still based on finding the header name contains the word email. But what if it contains some oddball header without the word email? Basically, I want it to do the data search first and determine what the header name is after.

Comment: @CrypticSage I've given you all the tools you'd need to find the information, it's ultimately up to you to write the logic.  If you have a more specific question and you've gotten stuck, then come back with a well-formed question.

Comment: That has been the question entirely. I can easily parse data based on header names. I don't want that. I want to parse the data based on that columns data and find out what the header name is after it finds the data. The reverse of what you provided. I've already attempted your example prior to asking the question.

Comment: @CrypticSage Without knowledge of your sample CSV, it's hard to know what can be done.  I've added a snippet that should work given the proper headers.

Comment: the reason I'm not providing headers is because they are unknown. Other users will be supplying the csv file needing to be processed. With user created files I've seen all kinds of oddball headers. So ignore that it has a header. Only focus on the data in each column and select that data based on a filter. That data on one csv could be on column 1 on another it could be on column 2 as well. Seems I'm not making any sense on what I'm asking.

Comment: @CrypticSage OK, updated for your requirement; I thought of an easy way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
$PathFile="c:\temp\test.csv"
$columnName=$null

$content=Get-Content $PathFile

foreach ($item in $content)
{
   $SplitRow= $item -split ','
   $Cpt=0..($SplitRow.Count - 1) | where {$SplitRow[$_] -match ".*@*.\..*"} | select -first 1

   if ($Cpt)
   {
       $columnName=($content[0] -split ',')[$Cpt]
       break
   }
}

if ($columnName)
{
   import-csv "c:\temp\test.csv" | select $columnName 
}
else
{
    "No Email column founded"    
}
```